# Open Xml Excel "Excel found unreadable content in <file>. recover the contents of this workbook?" after writing in Excel file VB.Net

Tags: xml, vb.net, winforms, excel, file-io

I am getting error after writing the data in the excel file using Open XML

Error is "Excel found unreadable content in . Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook?"

Here is the Code Snipped that I am using for reading/writing the Excel File using Open XML.

Some part of the code is taken from MSDN Site.

```vb
Private Function GetWorksheetPartByName(sheetName As String) As WorksheetPart
    Dim sheets As IEnumerable(Of Sheet) = _document.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild(Of Sheets)().Elements(Of Sheet)().Where(Function(s) s.Name = sheetName)

    If sheets.Count() = 0 Then
        ' The specified worksheet does not exist.
        _logger.Error(String.Format("Worksheet {0} not found in {1}", sheetName, _fileName))

        'Throw New Exception(String.Format("Worksheet {0} not found in {1}", sheetName, _fileName))
        'MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Worksheet {0} not found in {1}", sheetName, _fileName), "Data Export", MessageBoxButtons.OK)

        If Not chkIgnoreSheetNotFoundMsg.Checked Then
            Dim customError As New CustomError
            customError.FileLocation = _fileName
            customError.PosAndMsg.Add(sheetName, Helper.SHEET_NOT_FOUND)
            errors.Add(customError)
        End If

        Throw New SheetNotFoundException(sheetName, _fileName)
    End If

    Dim relationshipId As String = sheets.First().Id.Value
    Dim worksheetPart As WorksheetPart = _document.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(relationshipId)
    Return worksheetPart
End Function

Private Function InsertCellInWorksheet(ByVal columnName As String, ByVal rowIndex As UInteger, ByVal worksheetPart As WorksheetPart) As Cell
    Dim worksheet As Worksheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet
    Dim sheetData As SheetData = worksheet.GetFirstChild(Of SheetData)()
    Dim cellReference As String = (columnName + rowIndex.ToString())

    ' If the worksheet does not contain a row with the specified row index, insert one.
    Dim row As Row
    If (sheetData.Elements(Of Row).Where(Function(r) r.RowIndex.Value = rowIndex).Count() <> 0) Then
        row = sheetData.Elements(Of Row).Where(Function(r) r.RowIndex.Value = rowIndex).First()
    Else
        row = New Row()
        row.RowIndex = rowIndex
        sheetData.Append(row)
    End If

    ' If there is not a cell with the specified column name, insert one.  
    If (row.Elements(Of Cell).Where(Function(c) c.CellReference.Value = columnName + rowIndex.ToString()).Count() > 0) Then
        Return row.Elements(Of Cell).Where(Function(c) c.CellReference.Value = cellReference).First()
    Else
        ' Cells must be in sequential order according to CellReference. Determine where to insert the new cell.
        Dim refCell As Cell = Nothing
        For Each cell As Cell In row.Elements(Of Cell)()
            If (String.Compare(cell.CellReference.Value, cellReference, True) = 0) Then
                refCell = cell
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        Dim newCell As Cell = New Cell
        newCell.CellReference = cellReference

        row.InsertBefore(newCell, refCell)
        worksheet.Save()

        Return newCell
    End If
End Function

Private Sub UpdateCell(text As String, rowIndex As UInteger, columnName As String)
    ' Open the document for editing.
    Dim worksheetPart As WorksheetPart = GetWorksheetPartByName(_sheetName)

    If worksheetPart IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim cell As Cell = InsertCellInWorksheet(columnName, rowIndex, worksheetPart)

        cell.CellValue = New CellValue(text)
        Dim val As Double
        If Double.TryParse(text, val) Then
            cell.DataType = New EnumValue(Of CellValues)(CellValues.Number)
        Else
            cell.DataType = New EnumValue(Of CellValues)(CellValues.String)
        End If

        ' Save the worksheet.
        worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save()
    End If

End Sub
 Private Function GetCell(columnName As String, rowIndex As UInteger) As Cell

    Dim worksheet As Worksheet = GetWorksheetPartByName(_sheetName).Worksheet
    Dim sheetData As SheetData = worksheet.GetFirstChild(Of SheetData)()

    ' If the worksheet does not contain a row with the specified row index, insert one.
    Dim row As Row

    If (sheetData.Elements(Of Row).Where(Function(r) r.RowIndex.Value = rowIndex).Count() <> 0) Then
        row = sheetData.Elements(Of Row).Where(Function(r) r.RowIndex.Value = rowIndex).First()
    Else
        row = New Row()
        row.RowIndex = rowIndex
        sheetData.Append(row)
    End If

    If row Is Nothing Then
        Return Nothing
    End If

    Return row.Elements(Of Cell)().Where(Function(c) String.Compare(c.CellReference.Value, columnName & rowIndex, True) = 0).FirstOrDefault()
End Function

Private Function GetCellValue(columnName As String, rowIndex As Integer) As String

    Dim stringTable = _document.WorkbookPart.GetPartsOfType(Of SharedStringTablePart)().FirstOrDefault()
    Dim c As Cell = GetCell(columnName, rowIndex)

    Dim text As String = String.Empty
    If c IsNot Nothing Then
        If c.DataType IsNot Nothing Then

            Select Case c.DataType.Value
                Case CellValues.SharedString
                    If stringTable IsNot Nothing Then
                        text = stringTable.SharedStringTable.ElementAt(Integer.Parse(c.InnerText)).InnerText
                    End If
                    Exit Select

                Case CellValues.Number
                    text = c.InnerText
                    Exit Select

                Case CellValues.[Boolean]
                    Select Case c.InnerText
                        Case "0"
                            text = "FALSE"
                            Exit Select
                        Case Else
                            text = "TRUE"
                            Exit Select
                    End Select
                    Exit Select
                Case Else
                    text = c.CellValue.InnerText
                    Exit Select
            End Select
        Else
            If c.CellFormula IsNot Nothing Then
                text = c.CellValue.InnerText
            Else
                text = c.InnerText
            End If
        End If
    End If

    Return text
End Function
```

I am calling UpdateCell method in loop for writing the values in the Excel Sheet. I am also reading the values from the sheet too using GetCellValue Method.

Code works fine but when opening the file, it gives the "***Excel found unreadable content in . Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook?***

It is not happening with every file. I am facing this problem in particular files only.